# Stabilize a state of equilibrium

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, stability-theory

I'm having trouble solving a control theory problem.
I have a differential equation:
$$\dot{x}=-2x+Cx\gamma(t)$$
And I know that $|\gamma(t)|\le1$
Can I make the state of balance stable by choosing $C=0\ or\ C=0.5\ or\ C=1\ or\ C=2$?
Or this block uncontrollable?

Comment: It seems to me that at C = 0, 0.5, 1, 2, the state of equilibrium will be stable. Checked by the function V (x) = x ^ 2. Am I right?

Comment: If $C = 2$ the differential equation can become $\dot{x} = 0$ namely when $\gamma (t) = 1$. So in this case you only have Lyapunov stability. In the other cases you have asymptotic stability.